# How to send payload and cryptographic signature over WebRTC data channel?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, arraybuffer, webcrypto-api

I have a use case where a peer must send a message and signature to another peer using WebRTC Data Channels. Unfortunately the signature generated using WebCrypto is an ArrayBuffer, meaning that when I use JSON.stringify() to send the object the signature is lost.

Is there a way to encode the ArrayBuffer signature that will enable me to transfer the stringifyed object over the Data Channel without compromising the signature on the receiving end?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the datachannels [binaryType](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcdatachannel-binarytype) to 'arraybuffer'? Then you should be able to transfer without using JSON.stringify.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem is I have 2 different data types: string and ArrayBuffer. These must be sent in the same transaction. I have attached them both to a JavaScript Object e.g. {signedText: <string>, signature: <ArrayBuffer>}. I just can’t find any suitable method to transfer this Object over a Data Channel.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/ and encoding the ASCII as binary.